# Build a customized representation of ASTs for java programs using jdt

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Suppose `Statement` is the abstract class to represent all kinds of program statements such as `WhileStatement`, `BlockStatement`, `VarDeclaration` and `Incrementor`. Similarly `Expression` can be instantiated with `Binary`.

Now given the following code snippet

```
int a = 3;
while (a < 10)
{
    while(a != 5)
    {
        a++;
    }
    a++;
}
```

How to use jdt to build the data structure defined above for the AST. Specifically the first statement will be an object of `VarDeclaration`, and the second an object of `WhileStatement` which has an condition of `Binary` and a body of `BlockStatement` which consists of another `WhileStatement` and `Incrementor`.

This customized representation will be used for some downstream analysis that are readily available.

Comment: "Customized" in what way?

Comment: @KevinAnderson using the self-defined classes mentioned

Comment: The classes provided by JDT are not adequate?

Comment: The JDT AST uses its own classes for the various objects, it does not provide any way to customize the classes. But the AST classes provide all the information that is available.

Comment: @KevinAnderson maybe you can give me an example to show what the JDT tree looks like

Comment: @greg-449 I am not customizing the JDT classes, I want to build my own AST based on JDT classes which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Just to sum up: you _know_ that you will be using JDT to compile Java code into an AST.  But you _don't_ know what that JDT-produced AST will look like.  And you then want to turn that JDT-produced  AST into another AST built from your own custom classes.  Have I got that all correct?

Comment: @KevinAnderson That's exactly right. Can you help?

Comment: For starters, Google "JDT AST" and dive right in.  That should lead you to some documentation that will tell you what you need to know about of the JDT AST compiler and its output.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I did some searching but had no luck after `final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); AST ast = cu.getAST();` I don't know how to traverse the tree.